# Unmounting child component throws can't call setstate on an unmounted component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

when i unmount child component i get can't setstate on unmounted component warning.

What i am trying to do?
I have a parent component ViewItems and child component ItemsList.
In the ViewItems component i retrieve the items list from the server using load_items method which in turn uses client.get_file method. and store those items list in state named "items". I call this load_items method in componenDidMount method. However this will not show the new details for another item.

To give a clear picture of the problem. Consider i render items in one page. When i click on one item it takes me to other page (in this case items component in mounted) and when i click a button click to view item details it lists the details related to that item. When i click the button to get back to list of items (page where we were before) and click another item. It should display details related to the new item clicked.

However, in this case when i click the new item it shows previous item details unless page refresh.

To overcome this, on componentDidUpdate i call this load_items method. This works. But, when i dont close the child component meaning the layout where details of item is shown...i get the can't call setstate on unmounted component warning. This error is shown after child component is unmounted.

Below is the code,

```
class ViewItems extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.default_root_item = {
            name: 'Items',
            index: 0,
            children: [],
        };
        this.state = {
            root_items: this.default_root_item,
            items: [],
        };
     }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.load_items();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.load_items();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unlisten_path_change();
    }

    load_items = () => {
        const file_name = 'file_name.json';
        client.get_file(this.props.item_id, file_name, 'json')
            .then((request) => {
                const items = request.response;
                this.setState({items: [this.default_root_item]});}
        this.handle_path_change(this.props.location.pathname);})};

        return (
            <ChildComponent            
                 on_close={this.handle_item_close}
                 root_item={this.state.root_item}/>)}
export default class ChildComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    <Items
        items={root_item}/>

function Items(props) {
    return (
        <ul className="Items_list">
            <div className="items">
            {props.items.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <Item
                        key={index}
                        item={item}
                     />
                );
            })}
            </div>
       </ul>
    );}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not make an API call in componentDidUpdate without making a check whether the props changed or not.

Second: While setting state from API request response, check if the component is still mounted or not

```js
class ViewItems extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.default_root_item = {
            name: 'Items',
            index: 0,
            children: [],
        };
        this.state = {
            root_items: this.default_root_item,
            items: [],
        };
        this._isMounted = true;
     }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.load_items();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.item_id !== this.props.item_id) {
          this.load_items();
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
        this.unlisten_path_change();
    }

    load_items = () => {
        const file_name = 'file_name.json';
        client.get_file(this.props.item_id, file_name, 'json')
            .then((request) => {
                const items = request.response;
                if (this._isMounted) {
                  this.setState({items: [this.default_root_item]});
                  this.handle_path_change(this.props.location.pathname);
                }
            })
    };
```